# Jenn Air dishwasher not circulating water properly

Tags: appliances

Model JDB4000AWS dishwasher fills and cycles ok but the water does not circulate as it should and dishes are not clean. I removed and cleaned all of the interior parts down to the food chopper blade at the bottom and put it back together but it still doesn't work. I ran the field service test by pressing "Heavy Wash" 5 times and then start and that came back ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the [User Guide](http://www.jennair.com/assets/product/JDD4000AWS_Use%20and%20Care_EN.pdf) has to say...

> ### Troubleshooting
>
> #### Spots and stains on dishes
>
> - **Spotting and filming on dishes**
>
> Is your water hard, or is there a high mineral content in your water?
>   Conditioning the final rinse water with a liquid rinse aid  helps
>   eliminate spotting and filming. Keep the rinse aid  dispenser filled.
>   Always use a high-temp option.  Is the water temperature too low? For
>   best dishwashing results,  water should be 120°F (49°C) as it enters
>   the dishwasher. Did you use the correct amount of effective detergent?
>   Use  recommended dishwasher detergents only. Do not use less  than 1
>   tbs (15 g) per load. Detergent must be fresh to be  effective. Heavy
>   soil and/or hard water generally require extra  detergent.
>
> - **Silica film or etching (silica film is a milky, rainbow-colored deposit; etching is a cloudy film)**
>
> Sometimes there is a water/chemical reaction with certain  types of
>   glassware. This is usually caused by some  combination of soft or
>   softened water, alkaline washing  solutions, insufficient rinsing,
>   overloading the dishwasher, and  the heat of drying. It might not be
>   possible to avoid the  problem, except by hand washing.  To slow this
>   process use a minimum amount of detergent but  not less than 1 tbs (15
>   g) per load. Use a liquid rinse aid and  underload the dishwasher to
>   allow thorough rinsing. Silica film  and etching are permanent and
>   cannot be removed.
>
> - **White spots on cookware with nonstick finish**
>
> Has the dishwasher detergent removed cookware seasoning?  Reseason
>   cookware after washing it in the dishwasher.
>
> - **Brown stains on dishes and dishwasher interior**
>
> Does your water have high iron content? Rewash dishes using  1-3 tsp
>   (5-15 mL) of citric acid crystals added to the main wash  section of
>   the detergent dispenser. Do not use detergent.  Follow with a Normal
>   wash cycle with detergent. If treatment is  needed more often than
>   every other month, the installation of  an iron removal unit is
>   recommended.
>
> - **Black or gray marks on dishes**
>
> Are aluminum items rubbing dishes during washing?  Disposable aluminum
>   items can break down in the dishwasher  and cause marking. Hand wash
>   these items. Remove  aluminum markings by using a mild abrasive
>   cleaner.
>
> - **Orange stains on plastic dishes or dishwasher interior**
>
> Are large amounts of tomato-based foods on dishes placed in  the
>   dishwasher? It may be necessary to use a stain removal  product to
>   remove stains from your dishwasher. Stains will not  affect dishwasher
>   performance
>
> **Dishes are not completely clean**
>
> - **Food soil left on the dishes**
>
> Is the dishwasher loaded correctly?  Can the spray arm rotate freely?
>   Did you choose the cycle that describes the most difficult soil in 
>   your dishwasher? If you have some items with heavier soils,  use a
>   heavier cycle. Did you use the correct amount of fresh detergent? Use 
>   recommended dishwasher detergents only. Do not use less  than 1 tbs
>   (15 g) per load. Detergent must be fresh to be  effective. Heavy soil
>   and/or hard water generally require extra  detergent. Is detergent
>   still in the detergent cup? Use fresh detergent only.  Do not block
>   the detergent dispenser. Is the water temperature too low? For best
>   dishwashing results,  water should be 120°F (49°C) as it enters the
>   dishwasher.
>
> ### Dish Washer Care
>
> #### Cleaning the Dishwasher
>
> Clean the exterior of the dishwasher with a soft, damp cloth and 
>   mild detergent. If your dishwasher has a stainless steel exterior, a 
>   stainless steel cleaner is recommended.
>
> **NOTE:** Do not clean the dishwasher interior until it has cooled.
>
> Clean the interior of the dishwasher, with a paste of powdered 
>   dishwasher detergent and water or use liquid dishwasher detergent 
>   on a damp sponge to clean the cooled-down interior. 
>   A white vinegar rinse may remove white spots and film. Vinegar is 
>   an acid, and using it too often could damage your dishwasher.
>   Put 2 cups (500 mL) white vinegar in a glass or dishwasher-safe 
>   measuring cup on the bottom rack. Run the dishwasher through a 
>   complete washing cycle using an air-dry or an energy-saving dry 
>   option. Do not use detergent. Vinegar will mix with the wash water
>
> Periodically clean the coarse 
>   filter cup located on the floor of 
>   the dishwasher drawer. Remove 
>   collected particles from the 
>   coarse filter cup.
>
> **IMPORTANT:** Do not start the 
>   dishwasher until the coarse filter 
>   cup is securely in place and 
>   flush with the coarse filter plate. 
>   Doing so may damage the 
>   dishwasher motor and/or spray 
>   arm.
>
> **Cleaning the Coarse Filter Cup**
>
> 1. Pull drawer out to its full extension. Remove rack inserts from 
>      rack and set aside.
> 2. To remove the coarse filter cup, unscrew the small cap, turning 
>      in a counterclockwise motion. Lift and remove the coarse filter 
>      cup out of the drawer.
> 3. Empty the cup of hard objects and food soil. Rinse cup under 
>      hot water.
> 4. Place the coarse filter cup back into the coarse filter plate and 
>      tighten the cap, turning in a clockwise motion. Make sure the 
>      coarse filter cup is flush with the coarse filter plate.
> 5. Replace the rack inserts.
> 6. Make sure spray arm rotates freely
>
> If you have a drain air gap, 
>   check and clean it if the 
>   dishwasher isn't draining 
>   well.

Have you tried all of this?

Is the dishwasher draining properly?

You might want to make a call to [technical support](http://www.jennair.com/flash.cmd?/#/page/customerservice/), or a local appliance repair person.